# Correct way to define a Gradle plugin property extension with Java?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to create a Gradle plugin in Java that has property extensions (not conventions, as this is apparently the [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589206/gradle-plugin-convention-vs-extension), [wrong](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_you_use_a_conventionmapping_to_do_the_following) way). For the record, I'm working with Gradle 1.6 on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04).

I've gotten as far as figuring out that the this should be done in the Plugin class definition. Here is A way of adding an extension. Create an extension class that contains your properties:

```
public class MyPluginExtensions {

    File sourceDir;
    File outputDir;

    public MyPluginExtensions(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
        sourceDir = new File(project.getProjectDir(), "src");
        outputDir = new File(project.getBuildDir(), "out");
    }

}
```

Now add these extensions to the project in the main plugin class:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {

        Map<String,Object> taskInfo = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        taskInfo.put("type", MyPluginTask.class);
        taskInfo.put("description", "Generates blah from blah.");
        taskInfo.put("group", "Blah");
        Task myPluginTask = project.task(taskInfo, "myPluginTask");

        // Define conventions and attach them to tasks
        MyPluginExtensions extensions = new MyPluginExtensions(project);
        myPluginTask.getExtensions().add(
                "sourceDir", 
                extensions.sourceDir);
        myPluginTask.getExtensions().add(
                "outputDir", 
                extensions.outputDir);
    }
}
```

This approach, however, doesn't seem to be correct. A new project property is shows up in the `project.ext` namespace. I expect to be able to address the plugin extensions as:

```
in my build.gradle:
myPluginTask.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')
myPluginTask.outputDir = file('the/output')
```

However, when I put such things in a gradle script that uses my plugin and try to set this property, gradle tells me I can't set it:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> There's an extension registered with name 'sourceDir'. You should not reassign it via a property setter.
```

So, what's the right way to add property extensions for a task in a Java-based Gradle plugin?

**EDIT:**

Based on some other SO posts, I tried just adding my extensions object in one shot:

```
// first attempt:
//myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("sourceDir", extensions.sourceDir);
//myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("outputDir",extensions.outputDir);

// second attempt
myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("myPluginTask", extensions);
```

This appears to work. However, Gradle is now complaining that I've added a dynamic property:

```
Deprecated dynamic property: "sourceDir" on "task ':myPluginTask'", value: "/Users/jfer...".
```

So, again, what's the right way to add a plugin extension property?

**EDIT 2**

So, taking yet another shot at this, I'm adding the extension to the project object and using the create method instead:

```
// first attempt:
//myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("sourceDir", extensions.sourceDir);
//myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("outputDir",extensions.outputDir);

// second attempt
// myPluginTask.getExtensions().add("myPluginTask", extensions);

// third attempt
project.getExtensions().create("myPluginTask", MyPluginExtensions.class, project);
```

However, this fails for a couple of reasons:

1. Creating a properties extension with the same name ("myPluginTask") as the task creates a collision between the task name and extension name, causing the task to disappear from gradle's perspective (and throw oblique errors, such as "No such property: dependsOn for class ...MyPluginExtensions").
2. If I provide a name that does not collide with a task name (e.g., "myPluginPropExt"), the create() method works, but DOES NOT add the extension in its own namespace as expected (e.g., `project.myPluginPropExt.propertyName` and instead adds it in the project namespace (e.g., `project.propertyName`) which is not correct and causes Gradle to throw a bunch of "deprecated dynamic property" warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is *a* solution to my problem:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {

        Map<String,Object> taskInfo = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        taskInfo.put("type", MyPluginTask.class);
        taskInfo.put("description", "Generates blah from blah.");
        taskInfo.put("group", "Blah");
        Task myPluginTask = project.task(taskInfo, "myPluginTask");

        // Define conventions and attach them to tasks
        MyPluginExtensions extensions = new MyPluginExtensions(project);

        // the magic extension code:
        project.getExtensions().add("myPluginName", extensions);
    }
}
```

Now I can set a value for one of the extension properties in my **gradle.build** file like so (and I don't get a warning about adding deprecated dynamic properties):

```
 myPluginName.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')
```

The final trick is to get this value in my Plugin's task:

```
public class MyPluginTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
        MyPluginExtensions extensions = (MyPluginExtensions) getProject()
                .getExtensions().findByName("myPluginName");

        System.out.println("sourceDir value: " + extensions.sourceDir);
    }
}
```

This works, but what annoys me about this solution is that I want to be able to put the extension properties in the same namespace as the task (e.g., `myPluginTask.sourceDir`) which I have seen in groovy-based plugins, but this apparently is not supported or just doesn't work.

In the meantime, hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The code is adding an extension to a task (rather than a project), which is rarely useful. After that, it tries to set `myPluginTask.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')`, which isn't possible because the extension was just registered under that same name.

Comment: Thanks for the first about not adding the extension to the task. I've now got something working by adding an extension to the project object instead. However, you've misunderstood what's going on with your second point: `myPluginTask.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')` is part of my gradle build script, where I'm trying to set that extension value for a specific build.

Comment: I understand, but that's not how extensions work. Client build scripts configure properties of an extension, not the extension itself.

Comment: Still not quite clear: The snippet (`myPluginTask.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')`) is from a **client/consumer build script** that uses my plugin and is attempting to set that value for a specific build.

Comment: The plugin isn't using extensions correctly. An extension is an object whose *properties* will be configured by client build scripts. As such it needs to have a custom type and not an immutable type such as `String` or `File`. For example, you could do `project.getExtensions().create("foo", MyPluginExtensions.class)`. Then build scripts can set `foo.sourceDir` and `foo.outputDir`. It's important to understand that an extension creates a new namespace under its target (`project.foo` in my example). It can't "blend in" like a convention.

Comment: Ah HA! I have tricked you into answering my original question! :) I thought the `project.getExtensions().create()` method looked like the right way to do it, but my attempts to do it that way have failed thus far (see **EDIT 2** of my question). I'll have another go at it and update my Q and A, as appropriate.

Comment: `getExtensions().create(clazz)` is generally preferable over `getExtensions().add(instance)` because it enhances the extension class in some ways (e.g. makes it implement `ExtensionAware`). It doesn't make a fundamental difference, though.

Comment: OK, I had another go at this, using `project.getExtensions().create()`. Short answer is that it doesn't work. When I run my consumer build script, it complains that all my plugins extension properties are dynamic properties, so it appears to me that the `.create()` method is not creating a separate namespace for my extensions (e.g., `project.myPluginName.extensionNames`), while `getExtensions().add()` **does**. Looks like a bug to me. Where do I file this for the Gradle team to take a look at?

Comment: Extensions have a mature implementation and are used extensively by many plugins. Therefore I recommend that you first take a look at the source code of other plugins (e.g. the extension samples in the full Gradle distribution, or the code quality plugins in the Gradle codebase) and their use of extensions. If after that you still think you've found a bug, please post a fully self-contained example at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Believe me, I've been looking at **a lot** of Gradle plugin implementations in the last two weeks. The problem is that only a handful of them are implemented directly in Java, and the mature ones (like the Java and Maven plugins) use Conventions, which is an internal API and us Gradle civilians are admonished to avoid it. Regardless, since I think Gradle is a pretty awesome tool, I'll definitely post this to forums.gradle.org and see what comes of it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When your task and your extension have the same name, you can do this in your **build.gradle**:

```
myPluginTask.sourceDir = file('the/main/src')
project.tasks.myPluginTask.dependsOn clean
```