# How to structure loosely coupled gradle Task-Properties?

Tags: gradle

Given the following Gradle-Task/Plugin-Combination

```java
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)

        def task = project.task('hello', type: GreetigTask)

        //don't know how/when to populate task-properties with extension-values here.
        //this does NOT work... properites don't get populated
        task.message = {project.greeting.message}
        task.greeter = {project.greeting.greeter}
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    String message
    String greeter
}

class GreetigTask extends DefaultTask {

    def message
    def greeter

    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println "${message} from ${greeter}"
    }
}

greeting {
    message = 'Hi'
    greeter = 'Gradle'
}

task helloDirect(type: GreetigTask) {
    message = "howdy"
    greeter = "direct task"
}
```

I want to provide a plugin to my users, where users can use the `GreetingTask` in two different ways.

**1st way**

Use the `GreetingPluginExtension` to configure the plugin-provided task `hello` with a configuration-block like this:

```java
greeting {
    message = 'Hi'
    greeter = 'Gradle'
}
```

**2nd way**

Let the user explicitly define/create tasks and set required values in task definition like this:

```java
task helloDirect(type: GreetigTask) {
    message = "howdy"
    greeter = "direct task"
}
```

I just found out that I can either use `message` and `greeter` properties directly from the `GreetingTask`-object to print out the greeting OR change the task-action to use `project.greeting.message`.

How can I achieve more flexibility? I want my users to have the option to use both.

Comment: +1 for use of the old school phrase 'loosely coupled'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found *a way* to achieve what i want...

Below just the parts i've changed. The problem is, I don't know if this is the gradle-way(tm) to achieve what i want, because `conventionMappings`seem to be the old/deprecated way of working with gradle. See: [Gradle plugin: Convention vs. Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589206/gradle-plugin-convention-vs-extension) and [How do you use a conventionMapping to do the following?](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_you_use_a_conventionmapping_to_do_the_following) (via SO: [Correct way to define a Gradle plugin property extension with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437273/correct-way-to-define-a-gradle-plugin-property-extension-with-java))

Does anyone have a better suggestion? Or is this the best approach?

`conventionMappings` don't seem to be documented very well.

```java
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)

        def task = project.task('hello', type: GreetigTask) 

        //using conventionMapping here
        task.conventionMapping.message = {project.greeting.message}
        task.conventionMapping.greeter = {project.greeting.greeter}
    }
}
```

```java
class GreetigTask extends DefaultTask {

    def message
    def greeter

    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        //excplicitly calling getters and setters here.
        //conventionMapping-properties seem to be evaluated before class properties
        println "${getMessage()} from ${getGreeter()}"
    }
}
```